# How I can delete useless addresses?

Tags: bech32-address

In Bitcoin app wallet

I created many addresses, which I need to delete. I tried to press, clamp, enter the settings. Nothing helped. Is it possible to remove unnecessary addresses?

Comment: Why do you need to delete them? This is generally not a good idea, and thus most wallets do not offer this option.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to remove unnecessary addresses?

Many wallets can show you a list of all the receiving addresses they have generated.

Some wallets do allow you to view a list of only those addresses with a non-zero balance.

Wallet developers probably don't want to allow deletion of addresses because of the customer support issues that would be raised if money were subsequently sent to an address that had been deleted from a wallet. They'd have to also provide a way to re-create deleted addresses.

So just providing a list of addresses with non-zero balances probably seems like a more sensible option to many wallet developers?

Comment: If a developer wants to allow deletion of address, how would that work? Any links to read more about deleting addresses?

Comment: @Prayank: Sorry, I don't have any good links or more insight really. I can see that hiding an unused address can be done but deleting an address is clearly risky. I seems problematic how you could then implement an undeletion for people who realised they made a mistake in deleting an address and now want to know if some transaction to that deleted address finally got through etc.